# Displaying aws SQS body in formatted json

Tags: amazon-web-services

While polling for events in my AWS SQS queues the event body is always in json. When I look at one of the event bodies the json appears inline like it was when it was serialized:

[image]

But following along with video tutorials I've seen the json content come through multi-line and indented formatted in the AWS UI. I can't get a screenshot because my OS screenshot app blacks out the video, but the output would look like this:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "2022-11-05T11:36:58.813Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:AIDAV54BWOAM3ARBNBY7E"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "99.53.194.182"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "XV16DQH2TTBJ49NH",
        "x-amz-id-2": "TWpfzyb6lxtsh/pF6T1IndrldjwjKdBJreBG4YBXKJu+HdUdS/YSg8ZclsI19wHGWkxCjUQ2Kl9OZi42baxXps46iehNJ0+A"
      },
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

I've looked through my aws console settings and I can't find anything that would enable the formatting.

Does anyone know how to enable this formatting? It's not a massive deal because really it would be just my application consuming these messages, but it would be nice to remove that troubleshooting step of pulling out the body -> pasting it into a code editor -> reformatting the json so it's readable.

Comment: Messages don't provide content-type, so the UI _can't_ format it; what you see is what was in the message. If you saw pretty-printed JSON, then the program that _produced_ that message formatted it before writing the message.

Comment: Normally I'd agree, but the video tutorials I'm following are showing event bodies in a pretty print format that were created via the AWS services. Like the above event was created via an S3 event notification. In the tutorial the body is shown in pretty-print even though there's no option for adding a content type to the s3 notification.

Comment: Hmm, and actually these tutorials have a Q&A section. I'm going to ask the lecturer as well to see how he got the pretty print. If he gives an answer I'll reply with it here if someone else doesn't beat me to it.